# What is the difference between volume editors and series editors?

Tags: publications, editors

I am filling out a **"Consent to Publish"** form and I need to fill out the **Volume Editor(s) field**. I tried to find out who these editors are, but all I found was the **series editors** and the **main editor**.

For example for the [Lecture Notes In Computer Science](http://www.springer.com/series/558) there are 12 series editors. I doubt that I should list all 12 of them. Are the volume editors a subset of series editors, or are these two concepts unrelated?

Comment: It seems odd that you should provide such information. I would at least have expected the journal (equiv) to have provided that information to you in some way.

Comment: @PeterJansson: This is fairly common with Springer's LNCS series. Usually the volume editors take care of collecting the copyright forms for Springer (so you are not communicating with the publisher but with random academics who are not that experienced with this particular process). Sometimes the volume editors remember to tell the authors what to write there, but not always. Of course you can ask the conference organisers, but I do not see much point in doing that. I just write something that is close enough. These are just copyright transfer forms; the data won't be visible anywhere anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is a paper in conference proceedings that are published in the LNCS series?

Usually volume editors = programme committee chairs (or at least the PC chairs are a subset of volume editors).

Just put the names of the PC chairs; it is close enough. The series editors are something completely different (related to the entire LNCS series, not this particular volume).

Answer (score 1):

You should ask the person who sent you this form (PC chair?) what to write there. Springer does advise them to send the form pre-filled. Volume editors are people preparing proceedings for the publications - but essentially, it is up to the conference organizers who will be listed there (e.g., whether to include BIG-SHOT-WHO-IS-EMERITUS-PCCHAIR and/or POOR-PHD-STUDENT-WHO-PROOFREAD-EVERY-PAPER). Thus, it is not easy for you as an author to guess... 
P.S. Or may be you googled for LncS copyright form?;)
P.P.S. Series editors supervise the series - i.e., they approve the proposals for publication in the series. They should not be listed in the copyright form